# Spring boot: maven package with specific profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, deployment

The goal is, to have `dev` and `prod` environments. For the local run to use `application-dev.yml` and for deploying to the server to use `application-prod.yml`

I have 3 configuration files

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: off
```

**application-dev.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    password: dev-user-pwd
    username: dev-user
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

**application-prod.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    password: prod-user-pwd
    username: prod-user
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

In the server, I have `maven` installed and trying to run

```
mvn clean package -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```

Here is the error log that I'm getting

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 10.966 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.partplug.api.ApiApplicationTests
contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.005 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlbeam/config/XMLFactoriesConfig
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlbeam/config/XMLFactoriesConfig
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlbeam/config/XMLFactoriesConfig
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xmlbeam.config.XMLFactoriesConfig
```

**In short:** the error says that, datasource and all sub-properties are not defined. Meaning, maven packager doesn't change the active profile to prod.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please, don't make environment specific artifacts but use https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config